# Sentry not logging errors when I am in debug mode in VSCode, but logging errors normally when I run the app with "flutter run"

Tags: flutter, sentry

I am having a weird bug with Sentry. Last week, Sentry was logging the errors impeccably, but this week it started to show a strange behavior. I always used debug mode in VSCode for the hot reload and such, and Sentry, right from the beginning, logged all the errors, but this week, it just stopped. After a bit of digging, I noticed that when I run the app via "flutter run" it logs, but when I run via debug mode, it doesn't. Does anyone know what could be happening? Dunno if it is code related, since it always worked and I didn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

Changelog says that on version 6.4.0-beta.1 onwards reporting errors in debug mode was disabled: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dart/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#640-beta1

This change is referring to printing Sentry's debug logs to the console, is that what you are referring to? Or is it about capturing data (sending to Sentry) in debug mode?

If not, I suggest creating a ticket in the GitHub repo explaining what's going on. And what version were you before, when it was doing what you expect, and the version that started the surprising behavior: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dart/issues/new/choose

IMO sending data to Sentry only in release builds is a better default since in dev mode you have errors going in the IDE's console. Most value out of Sentry comes from running it in production. After you've uploaded all debug files, source maps, proguard mapping files, etc. So you get real world data, from all types of devices in the wild. But of course that's a matter of preference.